# Visual Studio Project Files and Source Control Bindings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-sourcesafe, projects-and-solutions, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am copying projects in one solution that is bound to VSS from one solution to another that is not bound (or shouldn't be).  When I copy the original project and add it to the new solution, it's showing as checked in and VS is remapping the working folder in VSS; I want this new copy to not be bound to source control and not do the remapping.  Is there anyway to disable it, even manually.  I can edit the project file if I have to, but I'm not sure what to delete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is manual, but you can try this out:

http://weblogs.asp.net/bkcarroll/archive/2004/03/08/86059.aspx

basically tells you which files and lines to clear out.

Answer (score 0):

You can also click File->Source Control->Change Source Control and unbind the project from SourceSafe.

Comment: But the problem there is I don't want to unbind from the original project, and if I leave it attached, copy the project to the new solution, and add the project, it moves the working folder because it sees the source control status.